# Finding an error in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

[image]I have this error in the logcat:

```
07-08 18:41:35.397  29820-30298/com.boolbalabs.petlinx E/SyncException﹕ java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Am I able to locate where this is occurring in the code from this information?

Answer (score 1):

If you double click the error, Android Studio will jump to the relevant file, and highlight the line on which the error occurs.

Comment: Cheers, I used to be able to do that but cannot any more. Am I looking at the wrong error view? I uploaded a screenshot of it.

Comment: Although it looks weird, it is the right view. Sometimes AS messes this up, try restarting it

Comment: No luck. So my Android Studio isn't behaving correctly? I can't find anyone else with this issue with a Google search.

Comment: The view of errors that are double-clickable is the gradle build view. So These are errors in there before compilation. Errors that occur during runtime may not be clickable?