# Android Studio error is always at line 1 on a very high column

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I need to locate an error in my code that shows up in the logcat as this:

```
07-09 02:42:02.251     939-1229/com.boolbalabs.petlinx E/SyncException﹕ com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 1501262120526111 at line 1 column 101693
```

As you can see it is at line 1, column 101693, which leads me to believe the code file has been minified at run time. It also does not say the file name, so I'm not sure what class file to look at either. Is there a way to unminify the code files so they say the line number and column number that I can view in my own code?

Please also see [this question that I asked yesterday which is a similar issue, but the error doesn't even say any line number or column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285375/finding-an-error-in-android-studio/31286001?noredirect=1#comment50576621_31286001)

Comment: @CodeProcessor What code do you want me to post?? There are 36 thousand lines of code. I am wanting to locate the error in the code from this error message OR create a better error message that is not on a minified file, so I can locate the error. I do not want help on fixing the error. This is about helping me to use the logcat in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is referring to the JSON file you are reading in.  The number 1501262120526111 is too big to fit in an int field.  Change the field you are reading it into to a long and it should read it.

Comment: I would normally agree with him that you should be able to click on it and it takes you to where it was thrown.  Another way might be to debug the app and  have it break on all Exceptions.  Directions [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28862538/1410671)